# BibTeX Warning----empty title

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm trying to compile my bib references with `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{nature}`. To my uttermost surprise BibTeX reports that some of the entries have an empty title, while IMHO the title is not empty, e.g., on the following bibliographic entries:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{WuWangZhaoMa,
author={Wu Kehe and Wang Zhuo and Zhao Xing and Ma Gang},
booktitle={Advanced Computer Theory and Engineering (ICACTE), 2010 3rd International Conference on},
title={Design and implementation of the monitoring system for EJB applications based on interceptors},
year={2010},
month=aug,
volume={4},
pages={V4-5--V4-9},
ISSN={2154-7491},
location = {Chengdu, China}
}
```

and

```
@inproceedings{DBLP:conf/sigdoc/TilleyH03,
  author    = {Scott R. Tilley and
               Shihong Huang},
  title     = "A qualitative assessment of the efficacy of {UML} diagrams
               as a form of graphical documentation in aiding program understanding",
  booktitle = {SIGDOC},
  year      = {2003},
  pages     = {184--191},
  ee        = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/944868.944908},
  crossref  = {DBLP:conf/sigdoc/2003},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
@proceedings{DBLP:conf/sigdoc/2003,
  editor    = {Susan B. Jones and
               David G. Novick},
  title     = {Proceedings of the 21st annual international conference
               on Documentation, SIGDOC 2003, San Francisco, CA, USA, October
               12-15, 2003},
  booktitle = {SIGDOC},
  publisher = {ACM},
  year      = {2003},
  isbn      = {1-58113-696-X},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
```

Comment: On the CTAN, the bibliography style file `nature.bst` is located in a directory named "/obsolete/biblio/bibtex/contrib/", and its file date is June 1992. This suggests the potential for some serious lack of compatibility of this style file with `natbib`. According to the header info in the style file, it's based on `unsrt.bst`. Is there maybe a more recent style file you could employ? You could start with either `unsrtnat.bst` or `plainnat.bst`. Another possibility would be `naturemag.bst`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've circumvented this problem (rather than actually solving it) by imitating the desired output with *[Makebst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/)*.

Comment: I'd call creating a new, bespoke bibliography style file a real solution, rather than merely a circumvention, of the problem. :-)

Comment: The problem is that I am not 100% sure that what I have done corresponds to the intended guidelines of the journal. It seems to match all their examples but Makebst has lots of options not covered by the examples.

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation of `natbib`, the following could be sufficient to get a style similar to what *Nature* uses:

```
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\bibpunct{}{}{,}{s}{}{\textsuperscript{,}}
\renewcommand\bibnumfmt[1]{#1.}
```

and then

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

Other possibilities are `unsrtnat` or `naturemag` in place of `plainnat`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work: it creates entires like First Author Title ... instead of Author, F. Title. An alternative I've found so far is just to ignore the warnings...

Comment: I've been wrong: you cannot just ignore these warnings since the titles are simply not put in the bbl...

Comment: Should `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` located at the top of the file or right before `\bibliography{}` section?

Comment: @alper That's immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

For me using

```
\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
```

instead of

```
\bibliographystyle{nature}
```

seems to have done the trick.

Comment: [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) doesn't offer `naturemag`, according to the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf).

Comment: chaging to naturemag i get an error which suggests that naturemag is not supported (as Werner points out):

! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.