# natbib nature citation styles

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm trying to use natbib in a manuscript draft using the document class nature. If I use the bibliography style naturemag, any citation I try to use with `\citet{something}` does not turn up correctly, and is given a missing author.

Is there any way to solve this, or is the naturemag bibliography style incompatible with `\citet` citations?

Comment: Please help us help you by providing the minimal code which produces this error. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: As [@Werner pointed out](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63511/bibtex-warning-empty-title#comment288384_128129) not too long ago: `naturemag` and `natbib` don't go together.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63511/5001

Comment: I agree that this question needs a lot more detail before it can be properly answered -- a MWE would help *tremendously*.